# What's the difference between reflow and repaint?

Tags: javascript, performance, repaint, reflow

I'm a little unclear on the difference between reflow + repaint (if there's any difference at all)

Seems like reflow might be shifting the position of various DOM elements, where repaint is just rendering a new object.  E.g. reflow would occur when removing an element and repaint would occur when changing its color.

Is this true?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This posting seems to cover the reflow vs repaint performance issues

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/

As for definitions, from that post:

> A **repaint** occurs when changes are made
>   to an elements skin that changes
>   visibly, but do not affect its
>   layout.
>
> Examples of this include
>   `outline`, `visibility`, `background`,
>   or `color`. According to Opera, repaint is
>   expensive because the browser must
>   verify the visibility of all other
>   nodes in the DOM tree.
>
> A **reflow** is
>   even more critical to performance
>   because it involves changes that
>   affect the layout of a portion of the
>   page (or the whole page).
>
> Examples that cause reflows include: adding or removing content, explicitly or implicitly changing `width`, `height`, `font-family`, `font-size` and more.

Learn which css-properties effect repaint and review at http://csstriggers.com

Answer (score 22):

**Reflow** happens when there is a change to the DOM layout. Reflow is very expensive computationally as dimensions and positions of page elements must be calculated again, then the screen will be **repainted**.

Example of something that will cause reflow

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++ {
const newEle = document.createElement('p');
newEle.textContent = 'newly created paragraph element';

document.body.appendChild(newEle);
}
```

The above code is very inefficient, causing 100 reflow processes for every new paragraph element appended.

You can mitigate this computationally stressful process by using `.createDocumentFragment()`

```
const docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

 for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++ {
    const newEle = document.createElement('p');
    newEle.textContent = 'newly created paragraph element';

    docFrag.appendChild(newEle);
    }

document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
```

The above code will now instead only use the reflow process 1x for the creation of  100 new paragraph elements.

**Repaint** is merely the changing of pixels on the monitor, while still taxing it is the lesser of two evils, since a reflow includes a repaint in its procedure.

Comment: instead of creating a document fragment, it would be the same if we create a parent div / span, right?

Comment: Is this actually true?

I thought if you call document.body.appendChild() in a loop, you're still in on the main stack. Until that stack clears, there will not be any repaints - so it's not actually any less efficient than document fragment?

Answer (score 16):

Great explanation that I found [here](https://gist.github.com/faressoft/36cdd64faae21ed22948b458e6bf04d5).

[image]

- `Reflow`: compute the layout of each visible element (position and
  size).
- `Repaint`: renders the pixels to screen.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, repaint just affects the DOM itself, but reflow affects the whole page.

Repaint occurs when some changes which only its skin styles, such as color and visibility.

Reflow occur when the page of DOM changes its layout.

Recently I found a site can search which attribute will trigger repaint or reflow.
http://csstriggers.com/

Answer (score 8):

Here is another great post: http://blog.letitialew.com/post/30425074101/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom

> A repaint, or redraw, goes through all the elements and determines their visibility, color, outline and other visual style properties, then it updates the relevant parts of the screen.
>
> A reflow computes the layout of the page.  A reflow on an element recomputes the dimensions and position of the element, and it also triggers further reflows on that element’s children, ancestors and elements that appear after it in the DOM.  Then it calls a final repaint. Reflowing is very expensive.

It also introduced when reflow occurs and how to minimize reflow.

Answer (score 1):

**Reflow** is the process of the browser laying out the page. It happens when you first display the DOM (generally after the DOM and CSS have been loaded), and happens again every time something could change the layout. This is a fairly expensive (slow) process.

**Repaint** happens after reflow as the browser draws the new layout to the screen. This is fairly quick, but you still want to limit how often it happens.

***For example,*** *if you add a CSS class to an element, the browser often recalculates the layout of the entire page—that's one reflow and one repaint!*