# box2dweb and kineticjs: poor update rate

Tags: box2d, kineticjs, box2dweb

folks ;)

Im doing a basic animation with box2dweb and kineticjs. Both frameworks are awesome. This is a preview of what im doing:
http://lab.devgf.com/boxkinetic/index_v.htm

When I see it in Google Chrome or Safari (desktop) it works really nice. Up to 60 fps. When I load this page with iPad's Safari the problem beggins.

If i use an iPad mini or iPad 2 (or even iPad 1) it works with an "acceptable" speed. Even inside Adobe DPS. BUT if the iPad is a retina model, (or with iPhone 5) there is NO speed. It is terrible, looks like "freeze".

Could someone help me? What should i do to get a nice framerate (or a different approach inside KineticJS loop) to make it works as it does inside desktop or no retina display device?

The main code to box2dweb im using is on this file:
http://lab.devgf.com/boxkinetic/js/tgf/gfbox2d.js

The main code to KineticJS is here:
http://lab.devgf.com/boxkinetic/js/Main.js

Any help is apprecciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Your link to your JS file is missing

Comment: looking at your source code on the preview, it seems that you have a lot of layers in the init() function, and with each step(), each layer gets redrawn, this is the main culprit of the slowdown on mobile devices.

Comment: Oh, @Mark. Sorry the broked link:
http://lab.devgf.com/boxkinetic/js/Main.js.

EliteOctagon: yes, there is on layer to each square/ball in the screen. But it updates correctly in "no retina" iPads. I will try to do all in the same layer and see what happens.

Comment: I admit I'm plugging my own similar question, but this could be a partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925958/phonegap-games-canvas-and-slow-javascript. A quick search indicates box2dweb can behave very oddly in mobile enviroments.

Comment: Hi all. The problem was the Kinetic.js. Im moving absolute div elements and with a good performance even on iPad 1 using box2dweb. Now, why Kinetic.js was breaking up i cant say. And yes, i try use only one layer. IMHO it is Apple's horrible canvas implementation on iPad Safari. (Desktop also. Chrome is muuuch more faster).