# Sencha Touch2 mvc app run slowly in android avd

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I made sencha touch2 mvc sample app by sencha touch2 cmd,but it run slowly in android avd.
why?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You need to provide additional infos like links to the sample app, hardware and sdk used, etc

Comment: Look at that post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450370/sencha-touch-2-android-performance

Comment: Did you build/compile you app for production ?