# html-5 canvas performance in android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-canvas

I'm using html-5 canvas and phone-gap to develop a simple scribble(drawing) app .it works very well in browser .but when i convert scribble html  to scribble.apk file using phone-gap and tried that in android device it works very very slowly .It means that it puts single dot in screen after 5 seconds from writing.

Is there any alternatives in html 5 canvas to improve better writing experience in android device? so that it will put the pixels in my screen without delay.

here is my code .

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
    y = 2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

function color(obj) {
    switch (obj.id) {
        case "green":
            x = "green";
            break;
        case "blue":
            x = "blue";
            break;
        case "red":
            x = "red";
            break;
        case "yellow":
            x = "yellow";
            break;
        case "orange":
            x = "orange";
            break;
        case "black":
            x = "black";
            break;
        case "white":
            x = "white";
            break;
    }
    if (x == "white") y = 14;
    else y = 2;

}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function save() {
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 4, 4);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="can" width="700" height="700" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:12%;left:43%;">Choose Color</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:green;" id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:red;" id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:yellow;" id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:43%;">Eraser</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:22%;left:45%;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:90%;left:10%;">
    <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:90%;left:15%;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some code. Do you use any libs/frameworks for canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is slow because of the android browser, see the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450370/sencha-touch-2-android-performance).

Besides native Code i dont think there are other alternatives. You could use this phonegap plugin:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas

It is only for android, and the canvas can only be showed in fullscreen. For more help i would need your sourcecode.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
You could try change the layer type of the view:

```
appView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); //or
appView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Comment: Yes ..I also tried with Fast-canvas but simply the same result.

Comment: Hmm well, the last thing i know you could try is to change the layer type of your View:
From hardware to software or vice-versa.