# What's the differences between rendering and painting event in Chrome DevTool Timeline View

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I think the `render` and `paint` just both mean rendering the page, show the DOM

What's the differences?

Comment: I'd guess it is just different naming for the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/q/2549296/1331430 but there may be something else now that Blink has changed the rendering a bit.

Comment: There are definitely not the same thing (what would be the reason for differentiating them on the timeline?). Anyway, @FabrícioMatté found the right link, it just uses different naming convention (render -> reflow, paint -> repaint).

Comment: "the same thing" I meant as in, render/reflow and paint/repaint.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Rendering events are about computing styles associated with each DOM node (i.e. "Style Recalculate") and elements position on the page ("Layout"). Paint category is about actually painting pixels and includes events like "Paint" itself and "Decode Image" / "Resize Image". In a nutshell, it's about inner structure vs. appearance -- if your page spends a lot of time rendering, this is because of the structure of its DOM and CSS (e.g. a large DOM tree), while significant paint times often mean the appearance of the page is affecting the performance (e.g. some styles are expensive to paint or an image is too large).

Answer (score 13):

```
 Rendering            Painting     

   ______________
  / E      F /   |
 ____________    |    ____________
 |      A    |   |    |     A     |
 |           | G |    |           |
 |           |   |    |           |
 | B      D  |   |    | B      D  |
 |           |   |    |           |
 |     C     | H/     |     C     |
 |___________|_       |___________
```

Comment: What does it mean? What are A,B,C ... etc?

Comment: This answer does not fully explain the difference. you could perhaps mention what the render process is actually doing vs what the painting process does.

Comment: i guess painting is flat. Literally painting(pixel) And the rendering is 3D it mean structure

Comment: I think this illustrates that painting is calculating the final colour of each pixel given all the elements on the screen, their opacities and who's on top of who.

Rendering involves calculating the appearance of each individual element, even if they're gonna be blocked by other elements overlaying on top of it.

Rendering is more towards the initial step while painting is the final step.

Answer (score 12):

In recent versions of Chrome (v51+) there are two relevant events in the timeline: **layout** and **paint** (there is no longer a "render" event).

- **layout** refers to the process of *construting a render-tree* and using that tree to compute the exact position and size of each object
- **painting** refers to the process of taking the previously computed positions drawing the colors to the screen

Layout has a notion of three-dimensions (z-indexes), structure (lines, boxes, flow) and parent-child relationships (trees). In painting, we flatten all of this information down to two-dimensions. The result of a paint is just a 2d-grid of pixels and their colors. It's what you see on the screen. All structure has been lost.

More information: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=en