# Will adding an out of the flow element cause a reflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I've got the following code I need to make sure is performance sensitive:

```
var $content = $(htmlString);

//Stop new element from triggering reflow? 
$content.css('display', 'none');

//add slide to DOM
$content.appendTo(options.els.$slider);
```

I can't remember if a reflow is triggered on any DOM manipulation or if there are exceptions like adding an out of the flow element to the DOM. Will the above code cause a reflow if `options.els.$slider` is in the flow?

Comment: Is this the jQuery `hide` method or some other framework?

Comment: I've updated the question to be a little clearer as to what's going on.

Comment: @DrewGaynor Looking at syntax, it certainly looks like jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`hide` method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) (or the [css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) as the updated question shows) sets the `display` property to `none`:

```css
display: none;
```

Which will cause the element to be removed from the normal document flow. If the requirement is to not remove the element from the normal document flow, change the `visibility` CSS property instead:

```
$content.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Setting the `display` property before adding it to the DOM, however, should not cause a reflow.

Note that changing the visibility once the element is added to the DOM will cause a [repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549296/830125), however. Paint events can be profiled using a number of different tools, including [Chrome Developer Tools on the timeline tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline).

Comment: Considering I am setting the elements display property to none before I insert into the DOM (am I correct in assuming that's what's happening?) will it trigger a reflow? This is what I am interested in.

Comment: @styke See my updated answer. The document flow shouldn't change as it's the element was out of the flow before it was inserted into the DOM. A repaint might be a different story though- I recommend using a tool as I mentioned in the answer to check for sure and do any profiling you may need.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser has it's own method of determining that, but typically, if your code is not causing any other elements to change, reflow won't happen. Just because you're appending to the DOM, doesn't mean the browser should repaint the page. You should be good.