# Image Enlarge on Hover

Tags: html, css

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/xakhLafd/

Hello,

I'm trying to have an image enlarge on hover and use an ease transition.  It works, but it seems to bug out sometimes. I tried to fix this by setting:

```
-webkit-transition-property: height,width;
```

But to no avail.  Also, I'm trying to understand how the author of this code (I got some of the code from a CSS blog) achieves this. I understand how on hover the image changes its width, but I'm not sure why the author is setting negative top and left values.  I have been trying to edit the width, height, top, and left to get the desired size on hover, but it seems to become skewed - probably because I don't understand what the negative top and left values are doing. Can anyone shine some light on this?  I've read some articles on negative margins, but I don't understand what's being done here.

Here's the code:

```
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/70497/pexels-photo-70497.jpeg" class="thumbnail"/>
.thumbnail{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    left:-35px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    z-index:999;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `top:-50px; left:-35px;` rule in CSS is used to keep the image's center-point unchanged after it is enlarged. Otherwise, when image is enlarged, you will feel it is moved to right-bottom side.

However, this is not a good design -- width/height change requires calculating new layout and redraw UI elements on every animation frame, which is very expensive (you can check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549317/707451) for difference between repaint and reflow). That's why you feel "it seems to bug out sometimes."

A better way is using `transform`. Please check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/Lrqu8L0q/1/) that fix  the issue. The new CSS code is:

```
.thumbnail{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:block;
  z-index:999;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
    transform: scale(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fiddle I created that fixes the issue. I got rid of position relative and set the height to auto instead of 100px.

here is the code i did.

```
 <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/70497/pexels-photo-70497.jpeg" 
 class="thumbnail"/>

 .thumbnail{
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
 }
 .thumbnail:hover {
     width:500px;
     height:auto;
     display:block;
     z-index:999;
     cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-transition-property: all;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
     -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Sorry forgot to update the fiddle here is the new link.

https://jsfiddle.net/xakhLafd/1/

Comment: Thanks, any explanation on the negative top and left?

Comment: I edited my code cause you probably had position relative there for a reason. I also got rid of the top and left so that it remains where it was how you left it.

Comment: Not seeing your changes

Comment: You won't see any changes. All I did was move the position relative to the .thumbnail class and got rid of the left and right so that it remains in it's inherit position. https://jsfiddle.net/xakhLafd/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple, this is code I'm working on atm:

```css
.box img {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    border: 2px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
 
.box img:hover {
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```