# Optimizing reflows if you actually need them

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, requestanimationframe

In my code, I have to remove a class, to get its full height. This is being done in `requestAnimationFrame`, but removing the class then querying `scrollHeight` will force a reflow. Do I simply need to query `scrollHeight` in `setTimeout`?

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  poo.style.overflow = 'visible';
  poo.scrollHeight;
  // Do something with it
  poo.style.overflow = 'auto';
});
```

Into...?

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  poo.style.overflow = 'visible';

  setTimeout(() => {
    poo.scrollHeight;
    // Do something with it
    poo.style.overflow = 'auto';
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: When you actually need the reflow, there's no reason to try to avoid it. Using `setTimeout` will at worst cause the element to flicker with the intermediate style.

Comment: @Bergi Are you implying that within a single frame, there can be multiple reflows/repaints, but only a single render? Or multiple renders in succession to reduce the "flicker" as much as possible?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple reflows before a single repaint. There would only be a single frame be painted.

Comment: @Bergi I'm confused because I read somewhere that if you reflow, it will also cause the page to repaint. Maybe it's due to misunderstanding, but from what you described, there is no such thing as a "repaint". There is only a single "paint" or none at all in a frame. Mind clearing this up, please?

Comment: TBH, I'm not quite sure any more. It probably depends on the implementation whether every reflow also does a repaint - they might as well be completely independent. (However, there definitely are repaints without a reflow, e.g. when scrolling or drawing on a canvas). Good reads: http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549296/1048572