# Modify :target in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, target

I have this in CSS :

```
#box:target {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
```

On a "parent" page (page1), I have a button that makes you go to another page : "page2.html#box". So the `#box:target` is applied when I the page is loaded. 
 But with a button on the page1, I activate a function which purpose is to change the `#box:target` properties. I'm looking for a way to change this in javascript. Not `:focus`.

Comment: `box-shadow property, after activate a function` can you please elaborate it

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. `:target` has **nothing** to do with focusing. Are you asking about focusing or targetting?

Comment: Can you just use :focus pseudo class with different styling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus ?

Comment: I would suggest using `:focus` or `:hover`. If you want a smoother animation and to avoid a [repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549296/whats-the-difference-between-reflow-and-repaint), I would suggest setting your additionnal box-shadow on the pseudo elements `:before` and animating it (see [How to animate box-shadow](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/))

Answer (score 1):

> ## Notice to Readers
>
> ### This Answer Concerns the Original Post First Draft

The OP has been edited to an entirely different question. So if this answer is confusing, you'll need to review the edits. I apologize for any inconvenience.

---

## [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

You do not need JavaScript for simple style switch. It appears that you have misunderstood the requirements needed to implement `:target` pseudo-class.

---

#### Requirements

1. Two `<a>`nchor tags and a tag of any type as the target.

   > ```
   >     <a>ON</a>  <a>OFF</a>  <section>SECTION</section>
   > ```
   >
   > One `<a>` will *"turn on"* the new `<section>` style and the other `<a>` will *"turn it off"*.
2. Next, the `<section>` needs an `#id`. Both `<a>` need an `href` attribute. The values of each `href` is different from the other and is specific (see comment below this example):

   > ```
   >       <a href="">ON</a>     <a href="">OFF</a>  <section id="S">SECTION</section>
   > ```
   >
   > **ON:** Must be    ☝              **OFF:** Must be a ☝
   >   the #id of target: `#S`    "non-jumping" value `#/`
3. In the CSS, add two rule sets:

   1. The first one is the target tag at default (***OFF***):

      > ```
      > #S { width: 44vw; height: 44vw; border: 4px solid #444 }
      > ```
   2. The second one is the target tag activated (***ON***). Suffix the `:target` pseudo-class:

      > ```
      > #S:target { text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px #444; }
      > ```
4. Here's what the HTML layout should look like more or less:

   > ```
   >    <a href="#S">ON</a>  <a href="#/">OFF</a>  <section id="S">SECTION</section>
   > ```

---

### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  font: 900 10vh/1 Consolas;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: cyan;
}

#B {
  box-shadow: 12px 5px 8px 10px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 6px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  font-size: 20vh;
  text-shadow: 4px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#B:target {
  box-shadow: 12px -5px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 4px -3px 0px #fff, 9px -8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}
```

```html
<a href="#B" class='on'>ON_</a><a href="#/" class='off'>OFF</a>

<figure id='B' class='box'>
  <figcaption>BOX</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question. I just want to modify the css rules when the element is targeted, change for instance the boxShadow property. I perfectly know what :target is for.

Comment: I absolutely didn't ask an other question. Yous just don't understand at all what I want

Comment: Explain to me what `.box:target` supposed to do and why there's no mention of a child or parent page in the first version of the post? Concerning the most current version, why did you change `.box:target` to `#box:target`? Also what is the significance of a parent and child page if there isn't any `<iframe>`? Also what happened to the function from the first version why isn't it in the current version? I probably don't understand but it appears that neither does anyone else -- have you read the comments?

Comment: Excuse me to not master the HTML perfectly, there are people who learn you know. So can't you just be normal please and explain me ?

Comment: And :target is used when the ilement is targeted with his id by an a tag with href="#element"