# resetting html content after selecting from the select box

Tags: javascript, html

I  am projecting the selected value with innerHTML, I want to reset the innerHTML after each selected value

```js
 const body = document.body;
    function dropdown(e) {
      const select2 = document.querySelector(".select");
      let selected = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = `<div>${selected}</div>`;
      body.appendChild(div);
      select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value = "";
    }
```

```html
<select class="select" onchange="dropdown(event)">
      <option>choose</option>
      <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Can you explain what *"reset HTML"* is? Resetting a form is a standard behavior, but resetting HTML isn't.

Comment: I think I figured out [what](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71374771/2813224) you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `<div>` in HTML instead of creating it everytime or you'll need to remove each one when a change event happens. When an element is removed or added to and from the DOM a reflow happens. A relow causes a broswer to recalculate position and distance of all content within the page. Changing an element that already exists on the page is less costly to browser processing. See this [question on reflows and repaints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549296/2813224). The example is a modified version of OP.

- Do not use onevent attributes. [Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these), so it's replaced by a onevent property handler, an `.addEventListener()` would be a better choice as well.
- The `event.target` Event Object property is used to point to the changed element (ie `.select`), `this` would also work. No need to do a `document.querySelector()` inside of function.
- Added `selected` and `disabled` to first `<option>` popup as an actual value.
- To get the current value of a `<select>` `.value` property will suffice.
- The `<div>` is referenced with `.nextElementSibling` of `.select` and the text is overwritten by `.textContent` property.
- Use `.selectedIndex = "0";` to reset `.select` instead of `.value=""`.

<sup>As per Oskar Grosser's comments below.</sup>

```js
document.querySelector(".select").onchange = dropdown;

function dropdown(e) {
  const sel = event.target;
  let selected = sel.value;
  const div = sel.nextElementSibling;
  div.textContent = selected;
  sel.selectedIndex = "0";
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option selected disabled>choose</option>
  <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I don't think the `select` element is supposed to reset. If so, that would be bad for accessibility.

Comment: There is no `default` property on `option` elements. Did you mean to use `selected`? Also, to disable selecting it, you can use the `disabled` property, which would effectively make this option a "placeholder".

Comment: Thank you, @OskarGrosser see update. As for the reset on `<select>` the OP's code has `select.value =''` which a reset seems to be the OP's intention .

Answer (score 0):

You can save the element to a variable and then remove it when the function is called again. (`oldDiv` in the example implementation below.)

```html
<select class="select">
  <option value="">choose</option>
  <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<script>
  let oldDiv = null // the newest created div will be stored here
  
  document.querySelector(".select").addEventListener("change", function(event) { // this way of adding an event listener is preferable, as it allows you to add multiple listeners to the same element
    if(oldDiv) oldDiv.remove() // remove the old div (if it exists)
    
    const div = document.createElement("div") // create new div
    div.textContent = event.target.value // set text content of new div to the selected value of the dropdown menu
    
    document.body.append(div) // add new div to body
    oldDiv = div // save new div in variable oldDiv, so it gets removed on next function call
  })
</script>
```